# How to open file after user select path and save in Java?

Tags: java, csv, file-io

I have a question about open csv file after save.
The situation is my program export data in .csv format and use JFileChooser to open dialog, after that user choose path and save.

Is there anyway to open exported file after save ? How can I get the path without fix it in code ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what about chooser.getSelectedFile().getName())

Comment: Reformulate your question; in general consider us dummies (I am). JFileChooser has an `showOpenDialog()` and a `showSaveDialog()` and the file can be gotten by `getSelectedFile()`. In the net are several demos.

Comment: I have never used JFileChooser in my life, but one quick look at the javadocs gives a hint to this answer immediately